# How to integrate msvc CL /DEBUG with visual studio devenv /DebugExe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I use msvc (visual studio cl.exe) on the command line to compile one of my c++ projects.

To do so, I use the Visual Studio Community 2019 developer console
In cmd, I initialize my environment by calling:

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
```

Then I compile my code with:

```
cl /DEBUG main.cpp SDL2-2.0.14\lib\x86\SDL2.lib portaudio_x86.lib /IPortAudio\include /ISDL2-2.0.14\include
```

Generally, I can run my program by just calling

```
main.exe
```

But if I want to debug it in visual studio, I use

```
devenv /DebugExe main.exe
```

In visual studio, after I hit "▶️start" in the top toolbar, the program will run fine, but when I hit an exception, the symbols wont load. For example:
[image: Visual Studio Community 2019 Debugger]

How can I get Visual Studio to **load the symbol file correctly** and show me the **LINE NUMBER** of the error?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Typically, MSVC uses so-called *program database* for debugging information, which is a separate file with the `.pdb` suffix, and usually is located in the same directory as the executable. Do your command generate such a file? If not then perhaps start a standard project in Visual Studio and look at what flags it uses when building.

Comment: Try adding `/Z` to your compile command to generate a pdb.

Comment: @RetiredNinja /Zi seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude /Zi seemed to do the trick. I had seen the /ZW flag in a separate visual studio project, but I never tried it. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out this only works when auto-linking with cl.exe in one step, otherwise the executable will not be built with the proper PDB, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-pdb-files-as-linker-input?view=msvc-160

Comment: Why not compile and debug directly from Visual Studio? Much simpler and faster as you never leave the IDE,

Comment: @Phil1970 vscode seems to be faster on my pc, visual studio is a bit too sluggish. Plus I like to write my own build scripts in batch and python, using cl.exe on windows or gcc on Linux. If I don't run into problems, I don't have to use devenv at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the answers provided in the comments to the question:

The compiling and linking must be done in one step since the executable is being compiled outside of a visual studio project:

to compile and link:

```
cl /Zi /EHsc <compiler options> <source files> /link <linker options> <library and resource files>
```

to debug:

```
devenv /DebugExe <executable>
```

Comment: What if I want to start the executable on a remote computer ? Is there a way to start the remote debugger from the command line ?

Comment: @Bemipefe Please create a new post for your question. It is not directly related. Thank you.